# Make the inputs of type checkbox come marked by the API and change their state at the time of their interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

Hello dev I hope you are well.
I would like the checkboxes to be checked by the API and change their status at the time of their interaction, the truth is that I have tried several things but I did not reach the solution

-Status of roles brought from the API that should be marked.

```
roles: [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Firmante"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Trabajador"
    }
]
```

-All roles also brought from the API

```
const[allRoles, setAllRoles] = [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Administrador"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Firmante"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Trabajador"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Gestión de Usuarios"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Admin Workflow"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Representante Legal"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Seguimiento de Notificaciones"
    }
  ]
```

-"roles" painted so far

```
<dt>
          <label className="mb-2">Roles</label>
            {allRoles.map(role =>{
              return (
                <div>
                  <label className="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    <input
                      name={role.id}
                      type="checkbox"
                      name="features"
                      class="new-control-input"
                      onChange={onChangeChecked}
                    />
                    <span class="ml-2 new-control-indicator">{role.name}</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </dt>
```

-UI Image
[image]

Thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `checked` property of the checkbox

Also you've defined `name` twice

```
<input
 name={role.id}
 type="checkbox"
 class="new-control-input"
 onChange={onChangeChecked}
 checked="checked"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use checked to set the condition for when the checkbox is checked but also value to make sure the correct value is passed when the onChange event is fired.
Sample implementation - https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dream-yv7kj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hello @Besnik Korça. Thank you very much for your reply, but the boxes have not been checked yet,
Example:
I would like these boxes to be checked.
roles: [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Signatory"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Worker"
        }
]

Comment: Check the codesandbox one more time I updated it - the 2 categories are prefilled. You achieve that by modifying the initial value of checked

`const [checked, setChecked] = useState(
    checkedRolesFromAPI.map(({ id }) => id)
  )`

Answer (score 0):

- use useEffect to mark the checkboxes coming from the api.
- create an array to hold all the ids of the checked ones.
- in the input use checked property to identify if the id is exists in the checked array or not.

  ```
  const [allRoles, setAllRoles] = useState([
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Administrador"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Firmante"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Trabajador"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Gestión de Usuarios"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Admin Workflow"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "Representante Legal"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Seguimiento de Notificaciones"
    }
  ]);

  const [checkedRoles] = useState([
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Firmante"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Trabajador"
    }
  ]);

  const [acceptedRoles, setAcceptedRoles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const rolesIds = checkedRoles.map((r) => r.id.toString());
    setAcceptedRoles(rolesIds);
  }, [checkedRoles]);

  const onChangeChecked = (e) => {
    let newCheckedRoles = [];

    const isExist = checkedRoles.filter(
      (r) => r.id.toString() === e.target.id
    );

    if(isExist && isExist.length > 0) {
       newCheckedRoles = checkedRoles.filter(
         (r) => r.id.toString() !== e.target.id
       );
     }else {
        newCheckedRoles = [...checkedRoles, {
          id: e.target.id,
          name: e.target.name
        }]
     }

    setCheckedRoles(newCheckedRoles);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <dt>
        <label className="mb-2">Roles</label>
        {allRoles.map(({ name, id }, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <label className="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-primary">
                <input
                  id={id}
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="features"
                  className="new-control-input"
                  onChange={onChangeChecked}
                  checked={acceptedRoles.includes(id.toString())}
                />
                <span className="ml-2 new-control-indicator">{name}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </dt>
    </div>
  );
  ```

[working sample demo - codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wozniak-4ye6l](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wozniak-4ye6l)

Comment: Thank you very much your answer is perfect but I would like you to save the state with this form at the time of marking them to send it again to the API already updated.
[
   {id: 3, name: "Signer"}
   {id: 4, name: "Worker"}
]

Comment: @PaulNuñez checked the updated version, now you have a state variable in the same form as what you get from the API. I only update the onChangeChecked function.